# What is the metal sheath surrounding a USB connector, and is it commonly connected?

Tags: usb, pinout

I was tearing apart a mouse for repairs and noticed that the small plug for the USB connection had a fifth connection. This connection had a much thicker wire than the other four.

I assume it is connected to the metal sheath on the male end of the connector, but what does it actually do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a shielding ground, usually made of copper braid. It stops stray signals from leaking in or out of the cable.

It should usually be connected at at least one end. I've seen conflicting advice over exactly how it should be connected to minimise noise and avoid ground loops.

Comment: What I've seen is that it should only be connected at the host end.

Comment: Yes. It should only be connected at the host end. If you connect at both end you've created a ground loop, which is not what you want. At the device end it can be connected to ground but through an RC filter and not directly.

Comment: Thank you for the help - the reason I asked is because I wanted to reuse a super-thin USB cable as a removable 5-pin connector.